# Material is always black and on Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I tried to assign different materials to face - they work correctly only on Eevee rendering.
[image]
When I tried to render using Cycles - the surface always black - doesn't matter what the material or base color, only 2 properties have value - Emission and Alpha, they work correctly, face orientation is ok on this face.

[image]

And the blend file

[image]

Comment: I guess your environment (World) is just a color, hence no reflections...

Comment: @brockmann yes, it is. But I already tried to change the world color to different colors - no effect on this face. It also correctly affects other facets, but not his one.

Comment: @brockmann no effect even with hdri.

Comment: @brockmann mb it is because I use Blender 2.9 alpha and It's a bug? Okay, let me try  stable version.

Comment: @brockmann added blend file

Comment: @brockmann deleting face and adding it again helped.

Comment: Indeed an issue with your geometry. Flipping the normals (*Alt-N > Flip*) as well as *Alt-N > Reset Vectors* fixes it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU5yH.png However, I'm not sure where this issue is coming from...

Comment: @brockmann thanks for your investigation!

Comment: Additionally you'd want to ensure that the geometry has thickness when using a transmissive material and the max bounces for the transmission should bet set to a reasonable value.

Comment: @RobertGützkow yea, my "glass" doesn't have a thickness. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mesh has [custom split normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/modeling/meshes/structure.html#custom-split-normals) in the problematic area. In order to see the split normals, switch to edit mode and enable *Display Split Normals* in the *Viewport Overlays*.

**Viewport Overlays**

[image: View split normals]

**Problematic Normals**

[image: Problematic normals]

If you have created the split normals intentionally you can edit them until they match the desired result (consult the manual for ways to [edit normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/normals.html)). In case the custom split normals were created by accident and you don't want them, they can be deleted in *Object Data Properties > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data*.

**Clear custom split normals**

[image: Clear custom split normals]

**Fixed Normals**

[image: Fixed normals]

When custom split normals are stored, *Auto Smooth* is automatically enabled. It can be disabled in *Object Data Properties > Normals > Auto Smooth*, in case you don't need it.

**Disable Auto Smooth**

[image: Disable Auto Smooth]