# Textures are completly black on Mac but work fine on Windows?

Tags: texturing

I imported an .obj file with a texture, originally exported from Reality Capture.
The texture shows completely Black(material preview).
I Tried importing the same file into the Blender on my Windows laptop instead of my Mac.
..and the textures are working fine there.
Tried it with .fbx as well, and it does the same.. PC shows, Mac does not.
I would really appreciate if anybody can tell me what's going on?
Im sharing screenshots..
B.

On Mac textures show black

[image: On Mac]

On Windows textures show fine
[image]

Comment: Are we missing one picture? Is the mac using an AMD GPU?

Comment: Susu,
Yes AMD Radeon HD 6970M 2048MB.
Both Pictures look like album covers.. should I just delete the pictures.. is it a bug?

Comment: You show two pictures that are the same image, so it  hard to understand the problem. Also, macs and AMD are the worst platform for blender. On top of that AMD's drivers have been having a lot of problems lately. Try downgrading to an older version or enabling high quality normals. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/amd-gpu-material-in-material-preview-mode-and-rendered-mode-is-entirely-gra

Comment: I corrected the images. The iMac is from mid2011, I prefer it because it has a big screen. Checked the link. enabling high quality normals didn't work.. looking how I can  downgrade the GPU driver to an older version on a mac.. thanks

Comment: Try clearing custom split normals https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175080/material-is-always-black-and-on-cycles/175127#175127 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120675/object-appears-black-while-rendering-while-other-objects-look-normal/120677#120677

Comment: Are the mac and windows running the same version of blender?

Comment: It looks like if you have a thunderbolt port you might be able to use the Mac as a secondary screen for the PC.  I actually do IT for a living, so I just happened to remember something about this:  https://www.techjunkie.com/how-to-use-an-imac-as-a-monitor-for-pc/

Comment: Sorry Susu, clearing custom split normals didn’t do the job either. I am using 2.91.0 on both computers. Additionally, I installed  Blender on a newer MacBook Pro and opened the same Blender file there, and it shows the textures. Following this, I uninstalled 2.91.0 from iMac and installed the latest 2.92.0 version. Unfortunately, textures don’t show again. I guess it's really the GPU then, isn’t it?. Bummer.. the old iMac is actually working wonderfully with Blender.

Comment: Hey Allen, Thank you for the advice. However, I’m confused.  Below I’m sharing both of my computers Specs

https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GT62VR-7RE-Dominator-Pro/Specification and,
https://support.apple.com/kb/SP689?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

Can you please tell me if I can actually use my iMac as a monitor for my PC laptop?
If so, do I need any specific cables or adaptors?

Comment: I solved this issue by decreasing my resolution to 1920 x 1080 from 2650 x 1440. It worked when I reassigned my image textures. It prefers working with smaller sized textures (MB wise) but it works. Good luck to those who have the same problem.